# Date Format not working in service class of spring?

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, date-format

```
public class DateCreation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date date = new Date();
            String format = sdf.format(date);
            System.out.print("date is:"+format);
    }    
}
```

This is working fine and output is: date is:2014-02-11

But when I use same syntax in Service layer of spring MVC than it results as:
date is:????-??-??

Here is code in spring. There is an @Override function in which I have used it.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String format = sdf.format(date);
    logger.info("current date is:"+format);
```

What could be the error?

Comment: That doesn't sound spring related at all to me. Probably you have a bug in your pattern variable

Comment: Please show us how you are using it in Spring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated it

Comment: What is your default `Locale`?

Comment: @gerrytan I have used same syntax and copied it into my code but its not working thought I thought

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not very fluent with spring? what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Make the two following calls `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());`. I believe you are use a different Locale and character set which your client cannot read.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis default locale is:en_US  and second thing outputed as Erroneous tree type: <any> and gave an error

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think second is UTF-8

Comment: So you're saying the logger code `logger.info(..)` is outputting `????-??-??`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes

Comment: Can you show the full code of spring class where you have this piece of code?

Comment: You see `????-??-??` in your log file (or in console)? Regardless, it would mean that `format` contains `????-??-??` and I don't see how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    }
```

Comment: It is for webDataBinder

Comment: Ankit, you can edit your answer if you need to. Also, how does this change explain the previous `??` in the printed logger statement?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have changed Locale as well still not working